# Unexpected behavior from VectorPlot

Tags: plotting

I am surprised at the behavior of VectorPlot in the following sense: plotting a vector field and examining the output at a point $(x_0,y_0)$ reveals that *Mathematica* doesn't draw the *tail of the arrow* at $(x_0,y_0)$ but rather it draws the *base of the arrowhead* at $(x_0,y_0)$. (Of course, the output points the arrow in the correct direction.)

This is, in my opinion, confusing/misleading for students learning about vector fields.

Has anyone developed an efficient workaround to this, so that when we plot the vector field we get output that positions the tail of the arrowhead at the point $(x_0,y_0)$ rather than the base of the arrowhead?

Here is some output which perhaps more clearly portrays the issue:

```
pts = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, -1, 1, .5}, {j, -1, 1, .5}], 1];
p1 = ListPlot[pts, PlotStyle -> {{Red, PointSize[Large]}}];
p2 = VectorPlot[{x + y, 1}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, VectorPoints -> pts, VectorScale -> Medium];
Show[p2, p1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The arrow is actually centred over the spot, so we simply need to shift the arrow by half its length:

```
Show[p2 /. Arrow[{p_, q_}] :> Arrow[{p + (q - p)/2, q + (q - p)/2}], p1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this accomplishes what I desire. It seems to me that this should be the default behavior of VectorPlot.

Comment: Have another Enlightened badge, Simon. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thank you. It's my first one actually :-)

Comment: @texasAUtiger: Your reaction to the default behavior was mine as well. But on my part this is due primarily because math textbooks and teachers draw the fields with the tails at the specified points; hence the dissonance for students who look at the Mathematica result. But in truth the Mathematica default may be more reasonable: having the middle of the arrow at the point gives a more realistic representation of the flow *through* the point, rather than the flow away from the point.

Comment: @SimonWoods: do you know how to incorporate these "shifted arrows" into something like `myVectorPlot` which calls `VectorPlot` but then shifts the arrows accordingly? I ask because I need to plot many vector fields and always want this tweaked behavior you posted.

Comment: @texasAUtiger, something like `myVectorPlot[x__]:=VectorPlot[x]/.Arrow[{p_,q_}]:>Arrow[{p+(q-p)/2,q+(q-p)/2}];SetAttributes[myVectorPlot,HoldAll]`

Comment: @SimonWoods: Perfect! Thanks.