# Visualize eigenvectors at specified points?

Tags: plotting, vector

I am very new to Mathematica and I got stuck about visualizing eigenvectors 2D and 3D.
I want to visualize my largest eigenvector field of tensor data(15x15). I wrote this code for instance :

```
points = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, 
2}, {2, 2}};

ListVectorPlot[{{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{2, 0}, {0, 
1}}, {{0, 1}, {1, -1}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{2, 1}, {-1, 1}}, {{0, 
2}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 2}, {-1, 0}}, {{2, 2}, {0, -1}}}, VectorPoints -> points, FrameLabel -> {x, y}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[points]}]
```

But my vectors don't begin from the specified point. `ListVectorPlot` function locate the vector in the middle of the point. Do you think I have to use another function like `Arrow` and `Graphics`?

In addition,I want to plot my second eigenvectors from the same point. For example, I have a matrix and its eigenvectors are {{1,1},**{-6,5}**} or {{4,5},{-1,3}}. At the end I have to multiply these vectors with their eigenvalues({{2,4}}) and visualize like that. How can I do that at specified points at an order and different lenghts of vectors(multiply with eigenvalues)?

Below you can find a basic example data,

```
datax = {{{{3, 4}, {4, 3}}, {{3, 4}, {4, 3}}, {{3, 4}, {4, 
 3}}}, {{{3, 6}, {6, 3}}, {{3, 6}, {6, 3}}, {{3, 6}, {6, 
 3}}}, {{{3, 5}, {4, 3}}, {{3, 5}, {4, 3}}, {{3, 5}, {4, 3}}}};
dataxv = Table[Eigenvectors[datax[[z, t]]], {z, 1, 3}, {t, 1, 3}];
dataxva = Table[Eigenvalues[datax[[z, t]]], {z, 1, 3}, {t, 1, 3}];
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @eolin For the second part of your question, can you give example data too? Just click on `edit` on the left side below your question and insert it.

Comment: Regarding the positioning of the arrows, see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8417/862) question.

Comment: @halirutan Thank you for your interest. I have done a bit what I have asked as a second question but I couldn't do it exactly.

Comment: @SimonWoods Thank you very much. As for me, It is a confusing problem that VectorPlot has.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Solution

You could use `Graphics`, `Arrow` and `s` which is a scaling factor and write

```
arrows = {{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{2, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{0, 
     1}, {1, -1}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{2, 1}, {-1, 1}}, {{0, 2}, {0, 
     1}}, {{1, 2}, {-1, 0}}, {{2, 2}, {0, -1}}};
s = 0.3;
Graphics[{Arrow[{#1, #1 + s*Normalize[#2]}] & @@@ arrows, Red, 
  PointSize[0.03], Point[#1] & @@@ arrows}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Explanation

`arrows` is a list where every element has the form `{p, v}` where `p` is the starting point and `v` is the vector to draw. The *Mathematica* function `Arrow` needs a starting point and an end point to draw something. We have the starting points explicitly, but the end-points need to be calculated. This calculation is simple: when we want to start at a point `p` and go along a vector `v` we just need to add them and we get the endpoint.

Let's further say, we want that all arrows have a constant length `s` than we could in a first step make `v` of normal length (meaning having length 1) and then we multiply `v` with `s`:

```
s*Normalize[v]
```

Therefore, if we want to define a `Function` taking `p` and `v` as parameter and which draws an arrow, it would look like

```
f = Function[{p,v}, Arrow[{p, p + s*Normalize[v]}]]
```

Now we want to use this function and apply it as easy as possible to your list of points and vectors `l` which has the structure

```
l = {{p1, v1}, {p2, v2}, {p3, v3}}
```

If possible, we want to transform this in one step into

```
{f[p1, v1], f[p2, v2], f[p3, v3]}
```

Here, `Apply` is very handy. The operators `@@` and `@@@` are infix forms for apply at level 0 and apply at level 1 respectively. What this function does is, it *replaces the `Head` of and expression with something else*. Example

```
Blub @@ Boing[1, 2, 3]

(* Out[7]= Blub[1, 2, 3] *)
```

The `Head` `Boing` was replaced by `Blub`. If you now consider, that `{1,2,3}` is nothing more than `List[1,2,3]` you see what happens when you do

```
Plus @@ {1, 2, 3}

(* Out[8]= 6 *)
```

With your parameter list, we need this replacement of the head *inside* the list, therefore we have to use `@@@`

```
Boing @@@ l

(* Out[9]= {Boing[p1, v1], Boing[p2, v2], Boing[p3, v3]} *)
```

If we now use `f` instead of `Boing` everything is like we want it to be:

```
s = 0.3;
arrows = {{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{2, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{0, 
     1}, {1, -1}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{2, 1}, {-1, 1}}, {{0, 2}, {0, 
     1}}, {{1, 2}, {-1, 0}}, {{2, 2}, {0, -1}}};
f = Function[{p, v}, Arrow[{p, p + s*Normalize[v]}]];

f @@@ arrows

(*
{Arrow[{{0, 0}, {0.212132, 0.212132}}], Arrow[{{1, 0}, {1.3, 0.}}], 
 Arrow[{{2, 0}, {2., 0.3}}], ...
*)
```

The last thing which need explanation is, that we don't really need to define `f`. We can just use it by writing the code where you need it.

```
Function[{p, v}, Arrow[{p, p + s*Normalize[v]}]] @@@ arrows
```

For the `Function` construct there is a shorter form where you don't give the parameters names like `p` and `v`. Just write the expression and refer to the first parameter as `#1` and to the second as `#2` **and** append an `&` at the end:

```
Arrow[{#1, #1 + s*Normalize[#2]}] & @@@ arrows
```

Now you should be prepared to understand the first code block in every detail.

### Update to your second question

You `datax` is a matrix of matrices having the following form

```
datax = {{{{3, 4}, {4, 3}}, {{3, 4}, {4, 3}}, {{3, 4}, {4, 3}}}, {{{3,
       6}, {6, 3}}, {{3, 6}, {6, 3}}, {{3, 6}, {6, 3}}}, {{{3, 5}, {4,
       3}}, {{3, 5}, {4, 3}}, {{3, 5}, {4, 3}}}};
MatrixForm[MapIndexed[Tooltip[MatrixForm[#1], #2] &, datax, {2}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I assume you want to plot the eigenvectors of the matrix in the upper left corner at position `{1,1}`, the vectors of the matrix right of it at position `{1,2}` and so on. (Run with the mouse over the entries if you evaluate the upper code. You'll see the positions).

Since I explained the first solution in detail, I will go a bit further now. Let's say we want a function, which

- takes a matrix `mat` and a point `point`
- calculates the `Eigensystem` of this matrix
- plots the normalized eigenvectors scaled by its eigenvalue as `Arrow`
- Shows the expression as `Tooltip` if you run with the mouse over it

Note, that I even `Normalize` the list of eigenvectors `{e1,e2,..}` so that their values are never bigger than 1 but the length-relation is kept alive. With this, the length of the arrows never exceeds 1:

```
drawSystem[mat_, point_] := Module[{evec, eval},
  {eval, evec} = Eigensystem[mat];
  {
   Tooltip[Arrow[{point, point + #1*#2}], 
      Row[{#1, MatrixForm[#2]}]] & @@@ 
    Transpose[{Normalize[eval], Normalize /@ evec}],
   Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[point]
   }  
]
```

Now, you could use `Table` in the same way you you already did (but we will **not**):

```
Table[drawSystem[datax[[z, t]], {z, t}], {z, 1, 3}, {t, 1, 3}]
```

instead let me introduce you to `MapIndexed`. `MapIndexed` applies a function to each element of a list (or a matrix, or a tensor in general) and gives as second parameter the position. Look at the following example:

```
MapIndexed[f, {{a, b}, {c, d}}, {2}]

(* {{f[a, {1, 1}], f[b, {1, 2}]}, {f[c, {2, 1}], f[d, {2, 2}]}} *)
```

This is exactly what we need for our situation. `f` is the drawing function and the matrix `{{{a, b}, {c, d}}` is the matrix of matrices `datax`:

```
Graphics[MapIndexed[drawSystem, datax, {2}], Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Outstanding answer!

Comment: @belisarius Thanks. I was afraid, that the code itself was useless to the OP. I started to explain it and it got longer and longer..

Comment: Oh well ... the OP posted the question and went away. So let's hope he returns to check this one!

Comment: @halirutan Thank you again, I want 's' to change at every point, how can I do that? I created a list for s and tried to apply it at every point but I couldn't succeed it.