# StreamPlot in Mathematica

Tags: functions

A $2\times 2$ linear ODE system can be visualized by `StreamPlot` in *Mathematica*. For example:

```
StreamPlot[{y, y - x}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

which gives

[image]

Or, this code:

```
StreamPlot[{y, -3 y - x}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

returns

[image]

Here is my **question**:

How can I draw a pair of eigenvectors (like arrows in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13821/664)) in the graph?

Comment: `Show` and `Graphics`? http://i.stack.imgur.com/CRGqu.png with the link you gave.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Öskå commented `Show` and `Graphics` is the way to go:

```
m = {{0, 1}, {-1, -3}};
ev = Eigenvectors[m];

Show[
 StreamPlot[m.{x, y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}],
 Graphics[{Red, Arrow[{{0, 0}, #}] & /@ ev}]
]
```

[image]