# Changing arrowhwead size and other parameters when plotting vector fields

Tags: plotting

When plotting vector fields how to keep arrow head size constant, have the arrow LENGTH proportional to the MAGNITUDE of each vector, change the thickness of the vectors (but keep this constant) and change the vector color.

It would also be nice to have the vector TAIL (rather than the vector midpoint) drawn from the appropriate vector point.

The problem seems to be that in v.10 the VectorStyle command only executes the first argument i

Comment: Likely related: [(58515)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58515/121)

Comment: Minor points of clarification: Your question seems to end mid sentence.  Is something missing, or is the final "i" a typo?  I'm not sure what "arguments" `VectorStyle` takes since it is an option, not a function.  3D or 2D?

Comment: Also related: [q/71787](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71787)

Answer (score 2):

This should give you a start:

```
VectorPlot[{y, -x}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
  VectorScale -> {Medium, 1/2, Automatic}, 
  VectorStyle -> {{Thick, Red}}
]
```

[image]

For changing the position of vector arrows please see:

- [Unexpected behavior from VectorPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8417/121)